# How to enable multiple row selection into a TStringGrid

Tags: c++, c++builder, stringgrid

I'm using C++Builder and I can't select multiple rows of my `TStringGrid` with the mouse.

Is there a particular property of `TStringGrid` that enable this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the `goRangeSelect` and `goRowSelect` flags in the [`TStringGrid::Options`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TDrawGrid.Options) property.

> goRangeSelect
>   Users can select ranges of cells at one time. goRangeSelect is ignored if Options includes goEditing.
>
> goRowSelect
>   Entire rows are selected rather than individual cells. If goRowSelect is included in Options, goAlwaysShowEditor has no effect.

Comment: Once I have selected multiple rows I need to sort them, but it sorts only the last selected row.
Do you know a way to move multiple rows together ?

Comment: To move them I need a fixed col

Comment: If you are having trouble moving/sorting rows, please edit your question to show the code you are trying to use.